# Calculate $3D$ coordinates of a vector based on $3$ angles relative to the $xyz$ axis and vector length

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, vectors, coordinate-systems, angle

A $3D$ vector is constructed by $2$ points, one being the origin $[ 0, 0, 0 ]$ and the other being $[ x, y, z ]$. Given the $3$ angles of the vector relative to the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis and the length of the vector, let's say $10$ units, how can we calculate the coordinates of $[ x, y, z ]$?

I am working on a robotics project. I can obtain $3$ readings on a gyroscope, the roll angle (relative to the $x$ axis), pitch angle (relative to the $y$ axis) and yaw angle (relative to the $z$ axis). The gyroscope is placed on a person's arm, and I would like to be able to represent the arm in a $3D$ space in the form of a vector.

One problem I face is that the arm undergoes more than $1$ rotation in different planes, so the rotations are not about the $x$, $y$ or $z$ axis. If the rotation is about one of the axes, then $2$ angles are enough to represent the rotation, and the formula that I found on the web would work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use a formula I found on the web:

 x = Math.sin(alpha)*Math.cos(beta);
 z = Math.sin(alpha)*Math.sin(beta);
 y = Math.cos(beta);

but that assumes the rotation is about one of the axes, so 2 angles (alpha and beta) are already enough to represent the rotation. The problem is the rotation I need is not necessarily about one of the axes, so I need a formula that involves 3 angles.